# Approximate roots using the binomial series.

Tags: approximation, radicals, binomial-theorem

as the title of the question says I need to approximate roots using the binomial series, I am new to this subject and I have had a hard time understanding how to do it. I have been researching and I have found that the binomial series is: $(1 + x)^n = 1 + \frac{n}{1}x + \frac{n(n-1)}{1*2}x^2 + ...$ At this point is my first doubt, can I use this binomial series to approximate roots of index two, three, four and so on? For example, if I want to find an approximation for $\sqrt{67}$ what I would do is: $(1 + 66)^\frac{1}{2} = 1 + \frac{0.5}{1}66 + \frac{0.5(0.5-1)}{1*2}66^2 + ...$ However, even with the second term of the series (Result = $34$) I am far away from the real value ($8.185352772$). Could you help me and if possible give me some examples of how to approximate roots of index two, three, four, five? In a further example, if I want to find an approximation for $\sqrt[3]{264}$ I would do something like: $(1 + 263)^\frac{1}{3} = 1 + \frac{0.3333333333}{1}263 + \frac{0.3333333333(0.3333333333-1)}{1*2}263^2 + ...$

Comment: The series for $(1+x)^n$ only converges when $|x| < 1$.

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks for the clarification, what could I do in that case?

Comment: You could use that $\sqrt{67} = \sqrt{100 \times .67} = 10 \sqrt{.67} = 10\sqrt{1-.33}$ and now apply the binomial series.

Comment: @jjagmath For the expression $\sqrt[3]{3}$ could I use something like $\sqrt[3]{1000*0.003}$?

Comment: Yes. However, be aware that this is not the best way to approximate roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series for $(1+x)^n$ only converges when $|x| < 1$.

So you need to find the nearest integer root. For $\sqrt{67}$, since $8^2 = 64$, you can write $\sqrt{67} = 8 \sqrt{67/64} = 8 \sqrt{1 + 3/64}$. Likewise, $\sqrt[3]{264} = 6 \sqrt[3]{264/216} = 6 \sqrt[3] {1+2/9}$.

Comment: I understand, what would happen in the case of $\sqrt[3]{3}$?

Comment: I have found something interesting, I want to calculate the following fourth root: $\sqrt[4]{1250}$, the nearest integer root is: $5^4$=$625$, So $5*\sqrt[4]{1250/625}$, $\frac{1250}{625}-1=1$ , However, the binomial series converges at $|x|<1$; How should I proceed in this case?

Comment: Then you have $5 \sqrt[4] {2}$ and now take a factor of $1.2^4$ out, since $\sqrt[4] {2} = \sqrt{\sqrt{2}} \approx \sqrt{1.4} \approx 1.2$, as $1+2x \approx (1+x)^2$ when $x$ is small.

Answer (score 1):

> With respect to comments from OP we look at approximation using the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* in order to calculate
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sqrt[3]{3}}&\color{blue}{=1.442\,249\,570\ldots}\tag{1}\\
> \color{blue}{\sqrt[4]{1\,250}}&\color{blue}{=5.946\,035\,575}\tag{2}\ldots 
> \end{align*}

**Approximation of $\sqrt[3]{3}$:**

Expansion of $\sqrt[3]{1+x}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{3}}{n}x^n\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad |x|<1\\
&=1+\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{1}{9}x^2+\frac{5}{81}x^3+\cdots\tag{3}
\end{align*}

In order to calculate $\sqrt[3]{3}$ we are looking for an appropriate scaling factor $y$ and make an Ansatz
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{1+x}=\sqrt[3]{3y^3}=y\sqrt[3]{3}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
We obtain from (4)
\begin{align*}
1+x&=3y^3\\
x&=-1+3y^3
\end{align*}
We know the expansion is valid for $|x|<1$, so we are looking for $y^3$ near $\frac{1}{3}$ which makes $x$ close to $0$. Since we want to do the approximation (at least in principle) manually we are looking for a rational value
\begin{align*}
y&=\frac{a}{b}\\
x&=-1+3y^3=-1+3\frac{a^3}{b^3}
\end{align*}
with small numerator and denominator. A table lookup of small values of $(n,n^3)$ gives
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrrrr}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
n^3&1&8&27&64&125&216&\color{blue}{343}&512&729&\color{blue}{1\,000}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
We observe
\begin{align*}
\frac{343}{1\,000}=0.343\approx \frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
is close to $\frac{1}{3}$ and we choose
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{y=\frac{7}{10}}
\end{align*}
as scaling factor.

> We obtain from (3) and (4) with $y=\frac{7}{10}$ and $x=-1+3y^3=-1+3\frac{7^3}{10^3}=0.029$:
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{y}\sqrt[3]{1+x}&\approx\frac{10}{7}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot0.029
> -\frac{1}{9}\cdot 0.029^2+\frac{5}{81}\cdot 0.029^3\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1.442\,249}61\ldots
> \end{align*}
> which is according to (1) accurate to $6$ decimal places. Note that lineare approximation
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{y}\sqrt[3]{1+x}&\approx\frac{10}{7}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot0.029\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1.442}\,38\ldots 
> \end{align*}
> is already accurate to $3$ decimal places.

**Approximation of $\sqrt[4]{1\,250}$:**

We can go on in the same way as before. Expansion of $\sqrt[4]{1+x}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{4}}{n}x^n\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad |x|<1\\
&=1+\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{3}{32}x^2+\frac{7}{128}x^3+\cdots\tag{5}
\end{align*}

In order to calculate $\sqrt[4]{1\,250}$ we are looking for an appropriate scaling factor $y$ and make an Ansatz
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[4]{1+x}=\sqrt[4]{4y^4}=y\sqrt[4]{4}\tag{6}
\end{align*}
We obtain from (6)
\begin{align*}
1+x&=1\,250y^4\\
x&=-1+1\,250y^4
\end{align*}
We know the expansion is valid for $|x|<1$, so we are looking for $y^4$ near $\frac{1}{1\,250}$ which makes $x$ close to $0$. We are looking for a rational value
\begin{align*}
y&=\frac{a}{b}\\
x&=-1+1\,250y^4=-1+1\,250\frac{a^4}{b^4}
\end{align*}

with small numerator and denominator. A table lookup of small values of $(n,n^4)$ gives
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrrrr}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
n^4&\color{blue}{1}&16&81&256&625&\color{blue}{1\,296}&2\,401&4\,096&6\,561&10\,000
\end{array}
\end{align*}
We observe
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1\,296}=0.343\approx \frac{1}{1\,250}
\end{align*}
is close to $\frac{1}{1\,250}$ and we choose
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{y=\frac{1}{6}}
\end{align*}
as scaling factor.

> We obtain from (3) and (4) with $y=\frac{1}{6}$ and $x=-1+1\,250y^4=-1+1\,250\frac{1^4}{6^4}=-\frac{23}{648}$:
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{y}\sqrt[4]{1+x}&\approx 6\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{23}{648}
> -\frac{3}{32}\cdot \left(\frac{23}{648}\right)^2+\frac{7}{128}\cdot \left(\frac{23}{648}\right)^3\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=5.946\,065}\,28\ldots
> \end{align*}
> which is according to (2) accurate to $6$ decimal places. Note that linear approximation
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{y}\sqrt[4]{1+x}&\approx 6\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{23}{648}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=5.946}\,75\ldots
> \end{align*}
> is already accurate to $3$ decimal places.